# handling server reboot in splunk alerts

Tags: splunk

I have splunk alerts set up. however when an application server is restarted, many log entries are created which trigger these alerts. I would like to either ignore these log entries or ignore the alerts when an application server is restarted.

Short of being able to do that, is there a way to annotate the splunk timeline? that way I could annotate the timeline and when people get alerted they can open the report and see that a server reboot occurred. Other tools with timelines allow this sort of annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement 'safe work times' is by using a lookup file. 
use the date_day date_hour type of fields to set the safe time, and then use the servername as the lookup field to get the data in, then use a where clause to filter out safe times.

**lookup file**

```
host      safe_begin      safe_end
myHost     1900             2200
```

**Query:**

```
.... | where date_hour!>=safe_begin AND date_hour!<=safe_end
```

after that, set your alert accordingly.